# SQL Server syntax error when using OPENROWSET?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I'm trying to write this as part of stored procedure on SQL Server 2000.  I keep getting a syntax error thrown on line starting Insert into OPENROWSET(.....

Help! I can't see the syntax error!

```
DECLARE @vDate Varchar(25) 
DECLARE @vCommand nvarchar(1000) 
DECLARE @fileName varchar(500)  

SET @vDate = LEFT(DATENAME(month, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE())), 3) + DATENAME(year, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()))

SET @fileName = '\\SERVER\folder\subfolder\subfolder\Excel\JobRerun\JobRerun_' + @vDate + '.xls'

SET @vCommand =  'copy \\SERVER\folder\subfolder\subfolder\Excel\JobRerun\JobRerunTemplate.xls ' + @fileName

Exec master..xp_cmdshell @vCommand , NO_OUTPUT

INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 5.0;Database=' + @fileName + ';', 
   'SELECT * FROM [RerunData$]')
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to reference a filename that will be different each time the procedure runs (once a month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do inline concatenation of string like you do in that line: 'Excel 5.0;Database=' + @fileName + ';'

Try moving that to a separate statement

You could try something like:

`exec ('INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'', ''' + @providerstring + ''', ''SELECT * FROM [RerunData$]''')`

Comment: This has got to be the problem!  But I tried doing it on a separate statement and I got the same error there too.  How else could I correct?

Comment: I'm not experienced with dynamic sql, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Create your statement as  string, and execute using the exec() function, like this:
exec ('INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'', ''@providerstring + ''', ''SELECT * FROM[RerunData$]''')

Comment: Your right, the inline concat is what confused it.  A) That SHOULD be allowed.  B) I got around it by copying my template to a temporary file which always has the same name, then inserting into that, and copying that file to give it the correct name with date.

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT statement is incorrect to me - you have `INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(...`.  That would imply that you're trying to insert into the OPENROWSET query, but you're supplying "SELECT *..." within it.  It should resemble:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(...
```

Comment: I'm trying to copy data from sql into the excel spreadsheet.  I copied this code from a working example and I'm trying to modify it to suit my needs.

Comment: The syntax I've seen working is INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(<params>) <select statement>

Comment: @Marc: The INSERT statement reads as trying to insert into the Excel spreadsheet, without any selection from the database table.  Based on the details, I don't think this is what you're after.